# Is there a better way to implement a multi-channel Writer monad in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

**Problem:**

I need to compose writer monads of different types in the same Haskell monad transformer stack.  Besides using `tell` to write debug messages I'd also like to use it to write some other data type, e.g. data packets to be transmitted in some other context.

I've checked Hackage for a channelized writer monad.  What I was hoping to find was a writer-like monad that supports multiple data types, each representing a distinct "logical" channel in the `runWriter` result.  My searches didn't turn up anything.

**Solution Attempt 1:**

My first approach at solving the problem was to stack `WriterT` twice along these lines:

```
type Packet = B.ByteString

newtype MStack a = MStack { unMStack :: WriterT [Packet] (WriterT [String] Identity) a }
  deriving (Monad)
```

However, I ran into problems when declaring `MStack` as an instance of both `MonadWriter [Packet]` and `MonadWriter [String]`:

```
instance MonadWriter [String] MStack where
  tell = Control.Monad.Writer.tell
  listen = Control.Monad.Writer.listen
  pass = Control.Monad.Writer.pass

instance MonadWriter [Packet] MStack where
  tell = lift . Control.Monad.Writer.tell
  listen = lift . Control.Monad.Writer.listen
  pass = lift . Control.Monad.Writer.pass
```

Subsequent complaints from ghci:

```
/Users/djoyner/working/channelized-writer/Try1.hs:12:10:
    Functional dependencies conflict between instance declarations:
      instance MonadWriter [String] MStack
        -- Defined at /Users/djoyner/working/channelized-writer/Try1.hs:12:10-36
      instance MonadWriter [Packet] MStack
        -- Defined at /Users/djoyner/working/channelized-writer/Try1.hs:17:10-36
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I understand why this approach is not valid as shown here but I couldn't figure out a way around the fundamental issues so I abandoned it altogether.

**Solution Attempt 2:**

Since it appears there can only be a single `WriterT` in the stack, I'm using a wrapper type over `Packet` and `String` and hiding the fact in the utility functions (`runMStack`, `tellPacket`, and `tellDebug` below).  Here's the complete solution that does work:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import Control.Monad.Identity
import Control.Monad.Writer
import qualified Data.ByteString as B

type Packet = B.ByteString

data MStackWriterWrapper = MSWPacket Packet
                         | MSWDebug String

newtype MStack a = MStack { unMStack :: WriterT [MStackWriterWrapper] Identity a }
  deriving (Monad, MonadWriter [MStackWriterWrapper])

runMStack :: MStack a -> (a, [Packet], [String])
runMStack act = (a, concatMap unwrapPacket ws, concatMap unwrapDebug ws)
  where (a, ws) = runIdentity $ runWriterT $ unMStack act
        unwrapPacket w = case w of
          MSWPacket p -> [p]
          _ -> []
        unwrapDebug w = case w of
          MSWDebug d -> [d]
          _ -> []

tellPacket = tell . map MSWPacket
tellDebug = tell . map MSWDebug

myFunc = do
  tellDebug ["Entered myFunc"]
  tellPacket [B.pack [0..255]]
  tellDebug ["Exited myFunc"]

main = do
  let (_, ps, ds) = runMStack myFunc
  putStrLn $ "Will be sending " ++ (show $ length ps) ++ " packets."
  putStrLn "Debug log:"
  mapM_ putStrLn ds
```

Yay, compiles and works!

**Solution Non-Attempt 3:**

It also occurred to me that this might be a time when I'd roll my own, also including error, reader, and state monad functionality that needs be present in my actual application's transformer stack type.  I didn't attempt this.

**Question:**

Although solution 2 works, is there a better way?

Also, could a channelized writer monad with a variable number of channels be generically implemented as a package?  It would seem like that would be a useful thing and I'm wondering why it doesn't already exist.

Comment: Sjoerd's solution is the way to go; however, why do you need your solution 1 stacked monad to be an instance of `MonadWriter`?  You should be able to define `tellPacket` and `tellDebug` as `Control.Monad.Writer.tell` and `lift . Control.Monad.Writer.tell` respectively.  You don't need (and can't have) a generic `tell` that covers both types (although you could make it an instance of only one type, say `String`, and call out the other as special).

Comment: I tried exactly that put ghci threw up with: "No instance for (MonadWriter [[Char]] MStack) arising from a use of `tell'".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The output of the `Writer` monad needs to be a `Monoid`, but luckily tuples of monoids are monoids too! So this works:

```
import Control.Monad.Writer
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import Data.Monoid

type Packet = B.ByteString

tellPacket xs = tell (xs, mempty)
tellDebug  xs = tell (mempty, xs)

myFunc :: Writer ([Packet], [String]) ()
myFunc = do
  tellDebug ["Entered myFunc"]
  tellPacket [B.pack [0..255]]
  tellDebug ["Exited myFunc"]

main = do
  let (_, (ps, ds)) = runWriter myFunc
  putStrLn $ "Will be sending " ++ (show $ length ps) ++ " packets."
  putStrLn "Debug log:"
  mapM_ putStrLn ds
```

Comment: deltaT = 10 minutes to an awesome answer.  I love this community!

Answer (score 8):

For the record, it is possible to stack two `WriterT`'s on top of each other:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import Control.Monad.Writer
import Control.Monad.Identity
import qualified Data.ByteString as B

type Packet = B.ByteString

newtype MStack a = MStack { unMStack :: WriterT [Packet] (WriterT [String] Identity) a }
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)

tellDebug = MStack . lift . Control.Monad.Writer.tell
tellPacket = MStack . Control.Monad.Writer.tell

runMStack m =
  let ((a, ps), ds) = (runIdentity . runWriterT . runWriterT . unMStack) m
  in (a, ps, ds)

myFunc = do
  tellDebug ["Entered myFunc"]
  tellPacket [B.pack [0..255]]
  tellDebug ["Exited myFunc"]

main = do
  let (_, ps, ds) = runMStack myFunc
  putStrLn $ "Will be sending " ++ (show $ length ps) ++ " packets."
  putStrLn "Debug log:"
  mapM_ putStrLn ds
```